# Magento 2.3 upgrade error Package container-interop/container-interop is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use psr/contain

Tags: magento, upgrade

I am upgrading magento 2.1.8 to 2.3.3 by command line it is showing below error when I run composer update command.

**Package container-interop/container-interop is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use psr/contain**

Any one let me know where i need to change to solve this problem.

Thanks

Sanjeev

Answer (score 1):

It comes up a lot during Composer installations. The module still installed, the message is just a false-positive. If it failed, the message would clearly state that.